# Java Loop every minute

Tags: java, time, loops

I want to write a loop in Java that firs starts up and goes like this:

```
while (!x){
    //wait one minute or two

    //execute code
}
```

I want to do this so that it does not use up system resources.  What is actually going on in the code is that it goes to a website and checks to see if something is done, if it is not done, it should wait another minute until it checks again, and when its done it just moves on.  Is their anyway to do this in java?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use [`Thread.sleep(long millis)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29).

> Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the specified number of milliseconds, subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers. The thread does not lose ownership of any monitors.

One minute would be `(60*1000) = 60000` milliseconds.

---

For example, this loop will print the current time once every 5 seconds:

```
    try {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(new Date());
            Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If your sleep period becomes too large for `int`, explicitly compute in `long` (e.g. `1000L`).

Comment: I tried it and it didnt work my code is as follows--
if (link.equalsIgnoreCase("exit") && count > 0) {
boolean fetched = false;
int myCounter = 0;

try {
while (!fetched) {
System.out.println("Checking (" + myCounter + ")");
if (session.areLinkDoneFetching()) {
session.getFetchData();
session.clearList();
fetched = true;
}
myCounter++;
Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
}
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}

Comment: What do you mean it "didn't work"? It doesn't compile? It doesn't sleep for 5 seconds at a time?

Comment: it runs once, and then doesnt do anything.  but the program is still running.

Comment: its something wrong with my code, sorry, it works well on its own. thank you though, this was exactly what i was looking for

Comment: Personally, I much rather prefer the solution user the `Timer` class below.

Comment: The `java.util.concurrent` package built into Java 5 and later is a replacement for the kind of code seen in this answer as well as supplanting the `Timer` class. See the [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) interface.

Answer (score 72):

You can use [Timer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

timer.schedule( new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
       // do your work 
    }
 }, 0, 60*1000);
```

When the times comes

```
  timer.cancel();
```

To shut it down.

Comment: If the `TimerTask` takes, say, 55 seconds to run, will this wait only 5 seconds before each run, or will it actually wait a minute like OP asked?

Comment: @poly: It will wait a minute like OP asked. The [Timer#scheduleAtFixedRate()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29) does what you say.

Comment: @BalusC: Ah, interesting! `schedule` runs with fixed delay between executions, and `scheduleAtFixedRate` runs at fixed interval. Nice!

Comment: I tried this one and put my code inside the run method but got an error about local variables being accessed from an inner class.

Comment: @Robert: Try making those variables `final` in that case.

Comment: What if we schedule the timer at fixed rate to execute Task every minute, but the task itself takes 1.5 minute to finish (executions overlap)? Would both task executions run in parallel? What would be an easy way to assure that whatever is accessed by run() method is prepared for concurrency?

Comment: Beside versatile options, beauty of this method is that it creates its own thread to do all the stuff. And in contrary to Thread-Sleep that .stop() method is deprecated, in Timer .cancel() can be called easily...     Thanks

Answer (score 15):

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
executor.schedule(yourRunnable, 1L, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
...
// when done...
executor.shutdown();
```

Comment: Don't forget to [shutdown()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown%28%29) it after use, else the thread will hang. Oh, the OP didn't ask for scheduling at fixed rate. Just use [schedule()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29).

Comment: note that it will not shutdown the thread if it's in a loop. shutdownNow will interrupt the thread also (which you need to handle)

Comment: you can use `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()` instead of `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);` if you need just one thread

Answer (score 9):

## `ScheduledExecutorService`

The [Answer by Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2703006/642706) is close, but only runs once. The Question seems to be asking to run indefinitely until an external state changes (until the response from a web site/service changes).

The `ScheduledExecutorService` interface is part of the `java.util.concurrent` package built into Java 5 and later as a more modern replacement for the old [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class.

Here is a complete example. Call either [`scheduleAtFixedRate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) or `scheduleWithFixedDelay`.

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool ( 1 );

Runnable r = new Runnable () {
    @Override
    public void run () {
        try {  // Always wrap your Runnable with a try-catch as any uncaught Exception causes the ScheduledExecutorService to silently terminate.
            System.out.println ( "Now: " + Instant.now () );  // Our task at hand in this example: Capturing the current moment in UTC.
            if ( Boolean.FALSE ) {  // Add your Boolean test here to see if the external task is fonud to be completed, as described in this Question.
                executor.shutdown ();  // 'shutdown' politely asks ScheduledExecutorService to terminate after previously submitted tasks are executed.
            }

        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            System.out.println ( "Oops, uncaught Exception surfaced at Runnable in ScheduledExecutorService." );
        }
    }
};

try {
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate ( r , 0L , 5L , TimeUnit.SECONDS ); // ( runnable , initialDelay , period , TimeUnit )
    Thread.sleep ( TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis ( 1L ) ); // Let things run a minute to witness the background thread working.
} catch ( InterruptedException ex ) {
    Logger.getLogger ( App.class.getName () ).log ( Level.SEVERE , null , ex );
} finally {
    System.out.println ( "ScheduledExecutorService expiring. Politely asking ScheduledExecutorService to terminate after previously submitted tasks are executed." );
    executor.shutdown ();
}
```

Expect output like this:

```
Now: 2016-12-27T02:52:14.951Z
Now: 2016-12-27T02:52:19.955Z
Now: 2016-12-27T02:52:24.951Z
Now: 2016-12-27T02:52:29.951Z
Now: 2016-12-27T02:52:34.953Z
Now: 2016-12-27T02:52:39.952Z
Now: 2016-12-27T02:52:44.951Z
Now: 2016-12-27T02:52:49.953Z
Now: 2016-12-27T02:52:54.953Z
Now: 2016-12-27T02:52:59.951Z
Now: 2016-12-27T02:53:04.952Z
Now: 2016-12-27T02:53:09.951Z
ScheduledExecutorService expiring. Politely asking ScheduledExecutorService to terminate after previously submitted tasks are executed.
Now: 2016-12-27T02:53:14.951Z
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a SpringBoot application it's as simple as

**ScheduledProcess**

```
@Log
@Component
public class ScheduledProcess {

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void run() {
        log.info("this runs every 5 seconds..");
    }

}
```

**Application.class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
// ADD THIS ANNOTATION TO YOUR APPLICATION CLASS
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulingTasksApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SchedulingTasksApplication.class);
    }
}
```