# Java String Date updated per minute locally

Tags: java, date, time

I have asked web service to return current time in city X. Then it return it as a String. E.g: 2012-11-24 19:30

Then I want to keep it running locally, means I need to update this time at least per minute. Obviously I don't want user to always make a request to web service to get the real time per minute.

Any good, efficient and effective idea how to implement this?

Thanks

Comment: Then show that code in your post :-)  people love relevant code here you see.... ;-) you can search similar posts to get an [idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702980/java-loop-every-minute)

Comment: Why do you need a web service call to return the current time in another city? Get the city's time zone instead (only once) and calculate it. If your machine's clock is off, sync it with a time server.

Comment: Thanks Max this is a better solution I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As recommended by @Max using timezone offset is what you really want to do, however to answer your literal question you may try something like:

```
Date remoteDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm").parse(string);
long offset = new Date().getTime() - remoteDate.getTime();
```

Now whenever want to get the current remote `Date`:

```
Date currentRemoteDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + offset);
```

Comment: Thanks Jibaly your answer makes sense too. Now which solution better? Your solution or using Timezone to calculate it?

Comment: If you can change your web service to return a time zone I'd go with that. If you don't have control of the web service go with the approach above.

Comment: @Jibaly, now another question would be what if my machine/local time is wrong? Then I would also get wrong time for the particular city. What is the solution? Check another of my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547720/how-to-get-current-time-on-another-city-correctly

Answer (score 0):

Use [java websocket](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket). in each minute, time will post to websocket connection and connection will tel to client update the time. Check the client server example and you could get idea of how websocket works.

(For this you need html5 support web browsers)